# Can't Install Node 12.8

Tags: node.js, installation, homebrew

I have been trying to install node.js on my Mac to use React Native. I tried many different times to install and reinstall node but I'd get a lot of errors.

I have tried installing on a fresh hard drive and I still can't seem to get it to work.

What I would try:

```
bash-3.2$ brew install node
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/node-12.8.0.mojave.bottle.t
Already downloaded: /Users/malqadi/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8ea6192c6101b64b58b3ff8bf0cab0b89eb67851ec11f5c95edda2fffcbdbfb0--node-12.8.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-12.8.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
Target /usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.8.0: 4,629 files, 53.1MB
```

I do what it recommends, but its the same:

```
bash-3.2$ brew postinstall node
==> Postinstalling node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
```

So I try brew doctor:

```
bash-3.2$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  node
```

How would I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the npm module with this command:

```
rm '/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp'
```

before linking node with this command:

```
brew link node
```